# I2C scan with Micropython and NodeMCU 12E returns empty list

Tags: i2c, nodemcu, micropython

I'm trying to hook up a `MPU6050` with my `NodeMCU` board with Micropython flashed in it.

My current wiring is the following:

```
MPU6050      Board
Vcc          3.3v
Gnd          Gnd
SDA          D6
SCL          D7
```

Through the command line, I've tried the following commands:

```
>>> from machine import Pin, I2C
>>> i2c = I2C(sda=Pin(12),scl=Pin(13))
>>> i2c.scan()
[]
>>>
```

12 and 13 were the GPIO values that I took from [this](https://cdn.instructables.com/FPV/E4YC/IKLFP40J/FPVE4YCIKLFP40J.MEDIUM.jpg) pinout and I've also tried with the D1 and D2 pins as many people online do.

Although I plan to use a premade module for reading the MPU6050 values, I would have liked to see this by myself (the pre-made modules seem too overwhelming, so I wanted to see if I could do something by myself).

I'm getting quite crazy because everything seems fine to me (according to other people's wiring seen online too).

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the code was right and the cause was a faulty contact in the breadboard.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else runs into this problem: After fighting for hours trying to get a NodeMCU work with a MCP23017 on micropython and getting the empty i2c.scan() I noticed that the problem is that for some reason micropython does not like using D1 & D2 (it does work when I test the same hardware configuration on arduino). Just use the following wiring for SDA and SCL in addition to the suggested wiring for the chip and you should be fine:

```
SDA: D6
SCL: D7
```

you should get:

```
>>> i2c = machine.I2C(scl=machine.Pin(13), sda=machine.Pin(12))
>>> i2c.scan()
[32]
```